# AWS SES - Able to receive few emails but NOT ALL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I'm trying to receive emails through AWS SES and process them through SNS and SQS, all works well for only 20-30% cases but not all. Any one got clue what is wrong here?

Current set up:

a) MX record has been set up on AWS Route 53.
b) 1 Email receipt rule has been set up to point to SNS topic, and SQS is subscribing to SNS, so that email messages are visible in SQS queue.

Now when emails are attempted to receive, some emails end up in SQS queue and some don't. The ones which do not end up in SQS queue, they are visible on the original mail server whose MX record was set up on AWS route 53.

Exactly same email from same email address with same text will land up in SQS queue, and after 1 minute on trying again will not land up in SQS queue, and will be visible on original mail server. So it is very random.

I have even unticked "Apply spam rules" in the email receipt rules, in case some emails are being refused by receipt rules because they are being identified as spam.

Searched through the forums, unable to find any help.

Any hint or help some one can provide will be much appreciated!!

Comment: i think there is a limit for SNS message publish(150KB), can you also try them to save to S3 and compare ?

Comment: @JamesDean Thanks James for your reply. Yes, I'm conscious of 150KB limit, here we are talking of "one word emails", exactly same email from same source will go through and on the next attempt, it will not. Yes, I have tried saving to S3 as well, exactly same behaviour, i.e. some emails will be saved and exactly same emails on other attempts will not, this proves it has nothing to do with SNS/SQS or saving to S3. Issue is that some times SES Receipt rules receive email and at the next instance, they don't, very weird, unable to find any mention of this issue anywhere on internet.

Comment: Whats your recipient rule look like, have you added "domain.com" this should allow to match the rule for all email address of recipient domain , also, you may not know if ses is bouncing back some emails unless sender receives it, try removing tls as well if it's enabled.

Comment: @JamesDean For S3 I added domain, but for SNS/SQS I added specific email like some@example.com, same result for both rule sets, all emails are being sent to some@example.com. You try 5 exactly same emails from same sender to some@example.com, 2 or 3 will reach SES, remaining 2-3 will reach the email inbox of some@example.com bi-passing SES, visible on www.example.com website, nothing gets bounced back to the sender. "Require TLS" is already disabled.

Comment: okay, this means you have mx records mixed up, when you resolve mx record for your domain(recipient domain), whats the mx records look like, if it is mix up with ses and some other records and if they have the same priority ? if so, it is possible that the sender MTA chooses the record randomly

Comment: Thanks @JamesDean, you were spot on, it was indeed the case of MX priorities. There were multiple MX records with same priorities, sorting that out solved the issue. Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, this means you have mx records mixed up, when you resolve mx record for your domain(recipient domain), whats the mx records look like, if it is mix up with ses and some other records and if they have the same priority ? if so, it is possible that the sender MTA chooses the record randomly – James Dean 2 days ago

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JamesDean, resolution was ensuring the right priorities in MX record set up. In my case, as part of the set up there were multiple MX records with same priorities, sorting the priorities out, resolved the issue for me.